# Can I create a map with a dynamic constructed comparer?

Tags: c++, stl

I want to create std::map in STL, but the comparer depends some dynamic value which is available only at runtime.. How can I make this? For example, I want something looks like `std::map<int, int, Comp(value1, value2)>`. value1 and value2 are not the compared number here, they are some kind of configuration numbers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a [functor class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object):

```
#include <map>

class Comp
{
public:
    Comp(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
    bool operator() (int a, int b) const { /* Comparison logic goes here */ }
private:
    const int x, y;
};

int main()
{
    std::map<int,float,Comp> m(Comp(value1,value2));
}
```

This is like a function, but in the form of a runtime object.  This means it can have state, which includes runtime configuration.  All you have to do is overload `operator()`.  If you define all the member-function bodies in the class definition (as above), then the compiler will probably inline everything, so there'll be negligible performance overhead.

If you know `value1` and `value2` at compile-time (i.e. if they are *compile-time constants*), you could use a function template instead:

```
template <int x, int y>
bool compare(int a, int b) { /* Comparison logic goes here */ }

int main()
{
    std::map<int,float,compare<value1,value2> > m;
}
```

Comment: The code is correct, but you don't really point out _why_ a functor is the solution. If you instantiate the map with the funtor _type_, you can (at runtime) pass a functor _object_ to the map constructor.